# trying to break down results of SQL query to show data for each month

Tags: sql-server

I'm very new to SQL and have a problem I can't figure out.

I'm trying to replace an excel spreadsheet and turn it into a PowerBi report. Currently our team runs the following query to get the amount of active users every month and types it into an excel sheet which then graphs the number of users each month showing the increase. Since I don't want to manually input data each month my goal is to break down this query to give the current number of users in each month and add to that every month.

Desired result would look something like this

```
dateCreated  # of Users
----------------------
2008-10      295
2008-11      355
2008-12      470
2009-01      522
```

I was able to break it down enough to give me the amount created each month, but that doesn't give me the total amount each month. This is the query that I used and a sample of the results I got.

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(USERADDR.DateCreated, 'yyyy-MM') AS 'dateCreated',
    COUNT(s.UserId) AS "# of Users"
FROM 
    ER.dbo.ssUser s,  
    ER.dbo.ssUserAddress USERADDR,  
    ER.dbo.ssAddress ADDRESS 
WHERE 
    s.UserId = USERADDR.UserId
    AND USERADDR.AddressId = ADDRESS.AddressId
    AND Isdefault = 1 
    AND Type = 'soldto'
GROUP BY
    FORMAT(USERADDR.DateCreated, 'yyyy-MM')
```

```
result sample: 
dateCreated # of Users
2008-10      295
2008-11      41
2008-12      22
2009-01      19
```

This is almost there, but I need a running total. I've tried a lot of different things including SUM, SUM OVER, COUNT OVER etc. My boss suggested a while loop. I can't get that to work either and everything I've read says that should be the last resort. Here is one example of my failed attempts

```
SELECT
FORMAT(USERADDR.DateCreated, 'yyyy-MM') as 'dateCreated',
COUNT(s.UserId) 
OVER(
    PARTITION BY Month(USERADDR.DateCreated)
    GROUP BY FORMAT(USERADDR.DateCreated, 'yyyy-MM')
    ) 

AS "# of Users"
FROM
       ER.dbo.User s,
       ER.dbo.UserAddress USERADDR,
       ER.dbo.Address ADDRESS
WHERE
       s.UserId = USERADDR.UserId
       AND USERADDR.AddressId = ADDRESS.AddressId
       AND Isdefault = 1
       AND Type = 'soldto'
```

```
--original query which gives total number of users right now. 
SELECT 
count(s.UserId) AS "# of Users"
FROM 
       ER.dbo.User s,  
       ER.dbo.UserAddress USERADDR,  
       ER.dbo.Address ADDRESS 
WHERE 
       s.UserId = USERADDR.UserId
       AND USERADDR.AddressId = ADDRESS.AddressId
       AND Isdefault = 1 
       AND Type = 'soldto'
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Are you certain you are measuring (or at least labelling correctly) what you think you are measuring. It is strange to rely on the creation date of a child row (address) as some indication that a user is "active" for any particular month. And you should make your assumptions clear to everyone - including those that use these numbers. Your counts are only correct if there is a 1:1 relationship between all three tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a window `sum()` on the aggregated count of users per month, like so:

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(USERADDR.DateCreated, 'yyyy-MM') [dateCreated],
    SUM(COUNT(s.UserId)) OVER(ORDER BY FORMAT(USERADDR.DateCreated, 'yyyy-MM')) [# of Users]
FROM 
       ER.dbo.ssUser s  
       INNER JOIN ER.dbo.ssUserAddress USERADDR 
           ON s.UserId = USERADDR.UserId,
       INNER JOIN ER.dbo.ssAddress ADDRESS 
           ON USERADDR.AddressId = ADDRESS.AddressId
WHERE Isdefault = 1 AND Type = 'soldto'
group by FORMAT(USERADDR.DateCreated, 'yyyy-MM')
```

Notes:

- *always* prefer proper, explicit join syntax (with the `ON` keyword) over implicit, old-school joins, who were deprecated *long* time ago - I modified your query accordingly
- SQLServer uses square brackets for identifiers - you should avoid single quotes, as they are generally used for litteral strings
- you have unqualified column names in the `WHERE` clause: always qualify column names in your query, so it is easy to understand to which table they belong

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate all your corrections and advice on best practices!